# MySQL using Filesort and Query is very slow?

Tags: mysql

I have a query :

```
SELECT listings.*, listingagents.agentid
FROM listings
LEFT JOIN listingagents ON (listingagents.id = listings.listingagentid)
LEFT JOIN ignore ON (ignore.system_key = listings.listingid)
WHERE ignore.id IS NULL
ORDER BY listings.id ASC
```

I am trying to improve the performance of this query since it is very slow and it is putting a heavy load on the MySQL server.

When I do a mysql explain, output shows :

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|     id | select_type |     table     |  type  | possible_keys |    key     | key_len |            ref             |  rows  |          Extra          |
+--------+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|      1 | SIMPLE      | listings      | ALL    | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                       | 383360 | Using filesort          |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | listingagents | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | db.listings.listingagen... |      1 |                         |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | ignore        | ref    | system_key    | system_key | 1       | const                      |    404 | Using where; Not exists |
+--------+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

I tried to do a simple query:

```
SELECT listings.*
FROM listings
ORDER BY listings.id ASC
```

And that query also have "Using filesort;".

The fields "listings.id", "listingagents.id" and "ignore.id" are Primary Keys
The fields "listingagents.id" and "ignore.system_key" have indexes.

What can I do to improve the 1st query?

Comment: What happens if you do a 'desc' on 'select * from listings order by id asc'?

Answer (score 0):

try to decrease listings range (currently 383360 rows) by adding some condition. e.g. id > x or limit.